# How to pause the animation of Sencha Animator from start?

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch

I've using Sencha Animator to do a simple animation.
I want to pause the animation from start. There have a button and when u hold the button it only play the animation.

How can I do that in Sencha Animator?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

listen to `onTouchStart` event to add animation and show the panel and `onTouchEnd` to hide the animated panel